# ibus not working in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, locale, ibus

I install lubuntu few days ago and I tried to add my locale(sinhala). By using command `ibus-setup` I got the ibus configuration window and then I add my locale. I can see the keyboard icon on the top bar and when I use key combination `ctrl+space` it change default English(US) to my locate. But that effects nothing. When I type all I get is English. I tried adding another locale and result is the same.

I tried running `im-switch -s ibus` which gives a error like

```
Error: no configuration file "ibus" exists.
Error: No action taken.
```

So I guess though ibus is running it is not set as the input method. Can anyone give me a hand here.

Comment: im-switch has been replaced with im-config. However, ibus should have been set already, so that's probably not part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should install the *ibus-m17n* package.

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
```

Then, next time you log in, you should see a bunch of new Sinhala options when running *ibus-setup*. Pick the one of your choice, and hopefully it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a really hard time making this work and finally solved my problem using `xfce4-xkb-plugin` on Lubuntu 18.04.

First install the plugin

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin
```

then right-click on the task-bar and click **add/remove panel items** , it will open a **Panel Preferences** window

Click the <kbd>+Add</kbd> button; it will open **Add plugin to panel** window
select **Keyboard Layout Handler** and click <kbd>+Add</kbd> button

Now back in the **Panel preferences** window select **Keyboard Layout Handler** and click the <kbd>Preferences</kbd> button

This will open the **Keyboard Layout Handler** preferences window, whereyou need to do the following:

Under **Advanced setxkbmap Options** uncheck *keep system layouts*

Under **Keyboard Layouts > +Add** select the language you want to add

Under **Change Layout Option** choose the keys you want to toggle between the languages

Now try it يعمل جيدا معي في اللغة العربية

Answer (score 0):

To add the functionality of multiple keyboards, first add (as root) to 
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart your language choices, for example, for US and French, add

@setxkbmap -layout "us,fr".

See http://lxlinux.com/#19 for additional information.